# Websockets not working on deployed Tomcat Server on Google Compute Engine

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, websocket, google-compute-engine

totally new to deploying apps with websockets so I feel like I'm missing something. I'm using Tomcat 8.5 on a Debian 8 instance. Steps I've done to deploy it on GCE:

1. Used the Click to Deploy for Tomcat.
2. Uploaded my .war file onto the deployed site.
3. Promoted the instance's IP to static.
4. Added firewall rule on port 80 with the target 'websocket'
5. Made a load balancer on the instance group of the server's instance. (Not quite sure if that helps or if I set it up right)

The load balancer looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hglj5.png).

My javascript creates the websocket like this (VDMServer is the name of the .war):

```
var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://[EXTERNALIP]/VDMServer/gameServerEndpoint");
```

And here's how I made the server endpoint class:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/gameServerEndpoint") 
public class GameServerEndpoint {
...
}
```

I am able to access the website on the virtual instance's external IP and the pages of my app, but even trying Tomcat's websocket examples give the error:

> Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Also here's how my Connecter in my server.xml looks like in /var/lib/tomcat8/conf:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Also seen solution about not including the javax websocket library so I made sure not to do that. [Here's what my .war's lib folder looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE9tz.png) That shouldn't affect the tomcat examples though right?

Any help on this case would be much appreciated, been looking for a way to fix this all day yesterday. Thanks!

Comment: Simple question: is the name of the .war file (`VDMServer`) also your contextroot when you deployed your application?

Comment: @Al1 Yes that's what it says "/VDMServer" in the Tomcat manager.

Comment: The error clearly states that your URL is incorrect. Classic mistakes are: wrong port, incorrect scheme (`ws://` vs `wss://`), context root. But I can't see more with the information you provided. By any chance, are the other resources such as web pages accessible?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked when I deployed a war without exporting any sources file.